# rvest Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the content from http://google.com.
the error message come out.

```
library(rvest)  
html("http://google.com")
```

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") :
>   Timeout was reached In addition:
>   Warning message: 'html' is deprecated.
>   Use 'read_html' instead.
>   See help("Deprecated")

since I'm using company network ,this maybe caused by firewall or proxy. I try to use set_config ,but not working .

Comment: have you also tried the `read_html` command, since the error message says `html` is deprecated... This might not solve you problem but maybe the output is more helpful...

Comment: yes,the message is :Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached
In addition: Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (http://google.com)

Comment: actually , this code works fine in my home network. but when I try to use this code in the company network ,the error comes up.

Comment: Seems not reproducible as a code issue, this returns a result for me. If you figured out what was going on with the network and how to work around it you could post that answer.

Comment: Same issue for me, apparently from the network I am using google asks proof of not being a bot, and the page of course times out when the scraper runs.

Answer (score 35):

I encountered the same `Error in open.connection(x, “rb”) : Timeout was reached` issue when working behind a proxy in the office network.

Here's what worked for me,

```
library(rvest)
url = "http://google.com"
download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
content <- read_html("scrapedpage.html")
```

Credit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38463559

Comment: That worked for me as well...  In my case I found a more permanent solution to be setting the proxy environment variables.  Here are the steps:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100844/1839959

Comment: Thank you- that worked for me, using company network.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably an issue with your call to read_html (or html in your case) not properly identifying itself to server it's trying to retrieve content from, which is the default behaviour. Using curl, add a user agent to the handle argument of read_html to have your scraper identify itself.

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)
read_html(curl('http://google.com', handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue because my VPN was switched on.  Immediately after turning it off, I re-tried, and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and a small hack solved it.
There were 2 characters in the hyperlink who were creating the problem for me.
Hence I replaced "è" with "e" & "é" with "e" and it worked.
But just ensure that the hyperlink still remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error message when my laptop was wifi connected to my router, but my ISP was having some sort of an outage:

```
read_html(brand_url)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: [somewebsite.com.au] Operation timed out after 10024 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

In the above case, my wifi was still connected to the modem, but pages wouldn't load via `rvest` (nor in a browser). It was temporary and lasted ~2 minutes.

May also be worth noting that a different error message is received when wifi is turned off entirely:

```
brand_page <- read_html(brand_url)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Could not resolve host: somewebsite.com.au
```