# Package "rvest" for web scraping https site with proxy

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrap a https website, but I failed.

Here is my code:

```
require(rvest)
url <- "https://www.sunnyplayer.com/de/"
content <- read_html(url)
```

But I have error in console- "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached"
How I can fix this problem?

Comment: That code runs for me without error. The problem may be specific to your proxy.

Comment: What setting am I need in R for proxy? plz help me.

Comment: I just know that it worked for me without a proxy. Your title mentions that you're using a proxy, so if that's the only difference between your setup and mine, then that must be the problem.

Comment: Plz write a sample code with example using proxy rvest

Answer (score 12):

The same thing happens to me on a proxy. To get around this, use `download.file` and specify a download location. You can then parse the file with `read_html`.

```
download.file(url, destfile = 'C://whatever.html')
content <- read_html('C://whatever.html')
```