# Rvest web scraping gives open.connection error

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to loop through a list of IDs to scrape some tables off Fangraphs. The below code works when I insert a single id and remove the for loop, but gives an error (i.e., Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.) when I reinsert the for loop. I've looked around at various places including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043172/package-rvest-for-web-scraping-https-site-with-proxy?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295686/rvest-error-in-open-connectionx-rb-timeout-was-reached?noredirect=1&lq=1), but nothing I try seems to work. I've also shortened my original list of 1000+ IDs to only 10 and still receive the error.

Can anyone help with this? Feel like this should be a pretty simple scraping task given the url is the exact same except for the IDs and the page layout is pretty straightforward. Thanks so much in advance.

```
for (id in pitchIDs$playerid) {
    url <- paste("https://www.fangraphs.com/statsd.aspx? 
playerid=",id,"&position=P&type=&gds=&gde=&season=all")
    gamelogs <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="DailyStats1_dgSeason1_ctl00"]') %>%
    html_table()
    gamelogs$id <- id
}
```

Comment: you can try with `paste0` to have an empty separtoru when concatenating your url. I am not sure a url with space could work.
If it is not that : can you provide a list of ID for reproductibility ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I solved the problem. Perhaps `paste0` helped do the trick. Thank you @cderv. See code below...

```
data = c()
for(id in pitchIDs$playerid) {
  url <- read_html(paste0("https://www.fangraphs.com/statsd.aspx? 
         playerid=",id,"&position=P&type=&gds=&gde=&season=all"))
  gamelogs <- url %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="DailyStats1_dgSeason1_ctl00"]') %>%
  html_table()
  gamelogs <- gamelogs[[1]]
  gamelogs$id <- id
if(is.data.frame(data)) {
  names(gamelogs) = names(data)
  data = rbind(data, gamelogs)
  } else {
    data = gamelogs
  }
}
```