# What does the HTTP error 544 means when scraping a page using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to use `rvest` to scrape [this page](http://rj.olx.com.br/rio-de-janeiro-e-regiao/imoveis/aluguel/aluguel-de-quartos?o=2). However, my code returns a HTTP error even though the page is working fine.

```
myurl <- "http://rj.olx.com.br/rio-de-janeiro-e-regiao/imoveis/aluguel/aluguel-de-quartos?o=2"
x <- myurl %>% read_html()
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 544.
```

What does this error mean? How can I avoid it? Am I getting blocked by the website?

Edit: Solved using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295686/rvest-error-in-open-connectionx-rb-timeout-was-reached).

Comment: you should make the "edit" an answer or delete the question.

Comment: Edit: Solved using [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295686/rvest-error-in-open-connectionx-rb-timeout-was-reached).