# HTTP error 400 using Google Maps API

Tags: r, google-maps, rjson, rjsonio

I am using the Google Places API to collect information about businesses. It has been working for more than 2000 queries but it has stopped now with the error

`Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400`.

Code:

```
require(RJSONIO)
require(jsonlite)
require(utils)
place_url <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query= "
key <- "Random_letters_generated_by_google"
setInternet2(TRUE)
query <- paste(business$name[1], city_name,country_name,sep = "+")
  str_url <- as.character(paste(place_url ,query,"&key=",key,sep=""))
  business_gis <- fromJSON(URLencode(str_url))
```

I have seen [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295686/rvest-error-in-open-connectionx-rb-timeout-was-reached) with the same error but related to html. How could I fix it for this case? Why has it stopped working? Any idea/hint is welcome.

Comment: I found the solution, it was a typo in the code leading to form the url. Morale: Errors on your connection may have nothing to do with the connection itself and more to usual typos/bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I had same problem, I took out spaces(replaced space with %20) and it worked for me.

Comment: For reference, my [`googleway`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/index.html) package has a `google_places()` function that should handle all the encoding for you.